# genbitmaptextbutton doesn't work on windows 7

Tags: python, wxpython

I try code from Another Tutorial 
http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Bitmap_Text_Buttons

But it doesn't run on  wxpython 2.8.12.1 and python 2.6, 
i've got this errors:

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_core.py", line 3473 
, in ImageFromBitmap 
    val = *core*.new_ImageFromBitmap(*args, **kwargs) 
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "bmp.Ok()" failed at ....\src\msw\dib. 
cpp(148) in wxDIB::Create(): wxDIB::Create(): invalid bitmap

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your bitmaps are not in the correct locations. Are you providing the "email.png", "calendar.png" and so on images? If yes, are you sure you are passing their correct path to the wx.Bitmap constructor?